# Que signifie « bocudos » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, littérature

Dans *D'un château l'autre* :

> il en venait même de plus en plus, adhérer, s’asseoir, et crever sous
> les pancartes… et devant les vitrines, de plus en plus de monde,
> regarder les grands-pères finir… « regarde ! regarde ! il fait sous
> lui ! » on vous parle des foules asiatiques, brahmanes, **bocudos**…

Savez-vous ce que signifie *bocudos* ?

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit très probablement d'un terme americano-hispanique qui signifie à peu près "bavard". Ca correspond à la description que l'auteur est en train de faire, en se référant à diverses contrées: Asie, Inde, Amérique, etc.
https://www.asale.org/damer/bocudo

Comment: Les "bouchus", c'est plausible.

Answer (score 1):

C'est ainsi qu'on désigne les vieux bavards et sans but au Brésil. En français, on pourrait dire "une commère". Au Brésil (et peut-être au Portugal ? Je ne suis pas qualifié sur ce point), on dirait Falador ou Bocudo.

Notez que c'est ici un nom, presque un statut ou une fonction, plus qu'un adjectif. On ne parle pas ici de quelqu'un qui serait *un peu commère*, mais de "**LA COMMÈRE** du village". Un vieillard peut être bocudo, comme un autre peut être prêtre, colporteur ou rebouteux. Et le sens en portugais du Brésil est moins péjoratif qu'en français : le bocudo autrefois (on pourrait dire "l'embouché" ou "le jacasseur") était surtout le chroniqueur, l'historien et le passeur d'anecdotes, utile à la société rurale et souvent illettrée de sa localité, plus qu'une simple commère : il y a du barde, dans le bocudo.

C'est dans cet esprit que Céline rapporte le terme à "brahmane".

Comment: À répétition, ton souhait.